# how to call aspx page in cshtml mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

i have control.aspx page in my mvc application which  have been added in ~/Views/Treeview/control.aspx

basically i am trying to use asp.net control in mvc application

what i have tried is 
below is my index.cshtml which is being callled on load of mvc app

```
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="callaspx" src="~/Views/Treeview/control.aspx"></iframe>

<body>
<head>
```

above thing gives me error in iframe The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /Views/Treeview/control.aspx

**i have even tried loading same page to div with help of javascript but no luck**

Comment: Try not putting it in your views folder, since it's a Web Forms page.

Comment: @mason: can you suggest where should i put aspx page

Comment: I did suggest. "Not in views". Why don't you start simple and just put it at the root of your site, verify that works, then move it around appropriately. Experiment. You don't need Stack Overflow to do that for you.

Comment: @mason: that was rude though but anyways thanx a lot it did worked!!!